# Disable a Button if the Terminated Dateis greater than today's date using JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a page in Razor with a button:

```html
<div class="panel-title createLink">
  <a href="@Url.Action("CreateSideLetter", "ClientSetup", new
  {
    page = Model.PagingInfo.Page,
    take = Model.PagingInfo.Take,
    sortBy = Model.PagingInfo.SortPropertyName,
    sortAsc = Model.PagingInfo.SortAscending
  })" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add Side Letter" id="createSideLetterLink"
    <span class="fa fa-file"></span>&nbsp; Create Side Letter
  </a>
</div>
```

In the database, there is a Termination Date. If the date is set to after the present day, then you cannot click the button. A tooltip is added and the button is red.

Is this possible to do with something like JQuery? Or could it be done using an IF ELSE statement in Razor?

Comment: It would make more sense to do this server side. Also note that you cannot explicitly 'disable' an `a` element. The closest you could come to would be to set `pointer-events: none` on it using a CSS class, but this is still easy to get around. I'd suggest setting `href="#"` on the relevant elements.

Comment: Also note that the opening `<a>` tag is missing a `>`

Comment: Okay if I went down the server side I would do it inside the controller?

Comment: That depends entirely on how your build your HTML. Given the example above it looks more like you need to do it in the View itself.

Comment: Is there the Termination Date in `Model` or not?

Comment: `Termination Date` is in the Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below in `View`:

```
<div class="panel-title createLink">
    @if (Model.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.TerminationDate > DateTime.Now)
    {
        // Set a tooltip and class
        <a href="#" title="your tooltip" id="createSideLetterLink"  class="your-class">
            <span class="fa fa-file"></span>&nbsp; Create Side Letter
        </a>
    }
    else
    {
        <a href="@Url.Action("CreateSideLetter", "ClientSetup", new
             {
                 page = Model.PagingInfo.Page,
                 take = Model.PagingInfo.Take,
                 sortBy = Model.PagingInfo.SortPropertyName,
                 sortAsc = Model.PagingInfo.SortAscending
            })" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add Side Letter" id="createSideLetterLink">
            <span class="fa fa-file"></span>&nbsp; Create Side Letter
        </a>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to add a `disabled class to it?`

Comment: @Rob Yes. For example you can do it like `<a href="#" title="your tooltip" id="createSideLetterLink" class="btn btn-danger">`.